# Debug applicationWillTerminate method call iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, terminate

In my application, I'm trying to cache data for which I'm saving all the objects in sqlite database in applicationWillTerminate call. This method is getting called whenever I'm pressing home button on simulator, but I want to debug the code inside the method, is it possible?

Or else I'll debug the code somewhere else and use it here.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: So adding a breakpoint in that method does not work for you?

Comment: For 4.0 apps I'd use applicationDidEnterBackground to save state btw

Comment: On 4.0 applicationWillTerminate is rarely called. Do this work in applicationDidEnterBackground as willcodejavaforfood said (presuming you're on 4.0)